# Check headers on each page request

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I need to check the request headers on each page request. I thought the place to try this would be in the 'apostrophe-express' module. I've created my own module 'auth' that extends 'apostrophe-express':

```
module.exports = {
extend: 'apostrophe-express',
name: 'auth',
alias: 'auth',
absoluteUrl: function(req, res, next){
    console.log(req);
 }
};
```

But this isn't working. I'm getting an error 'apostrophe-templates\index.js" 597  req.browserCall('apos.pageReadywhenCalm($("body"));')'

Can you tell me where I should hook into each page request to run some custom checking/rule (e.g. if a certain cookie isnt present, then redirect the user to a different site)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm the principal architect of Apostrophe at P'unk Avenue.

You don't want to extend the `apostrophe-express` module under a new name. That module provides the `apos.app` singleton, so extending it under a new name just sets up `apos.app` twice, leading to confusion and potential problems.

#### Intercepting every Express request

Instead, just leverage the `middleware` option of the `apostrophe-express` module. You can do that in `app.js`:

```
var apos = require('apostrophe')({
  modules: {
    // Other module configuration here, then ...
    'apostrophe-express': {
      middleware: [
        function(req, res, next) {
          // Do whatever you like here
          console.log(req.url);
          // Let the request continue. You could also
          // use res.redirect, res.send, etc. and
          // bypass Apostrophe, in which case you
          // should NOT call next
          return next();
        }
      ]
    }
  }
});
```

This is all you need, and you could use `require` to pull the middleware function in from another file, reducing clutter in `app.js`. However it's worth pointing out that you can move this code to a `lib/modules/apostrophe-express/index.js` file in your project, to "implicitly subclass" that module. That opens the door to providing your own `construct` property as well, which would permit you to override any of the methods of the module if you wanted to.

If you approach it this way, you don't need to touch `app.js` at all:

```
// in lib/modules/apostrophe-express/index.js at project level
module.exports = {
  middleware: [
    function(req, res, next) {
      console.log(req.url);
      return next();
    }
  ],
  construct: function(self, options) {
    // If you want, override methods of the module here   
  };
};
```

#### Intercepting the request just before page rendering

You specified "each page request," which I've interpreted to mean "each web request." But it's possible you specifically only want requests where Apostrophe is about to build and send a proper webpage.

For that, just add a `pageBeforeSend` method to any of your own modules. Let's say our module is called `cool-stuff`:

```
// in app.js

var apos = require('apostrophe')({
  modules: {
    // Other module configuration here, then ...
   'cool-stuff': {}
  }
});


// In lib/modules/cool-stuff/index.js

module.exports = {
  construct: function(self, options) {
    self.pageBeforeSend = function(req, callback) {
      // Careful, there isn't always a page object; we could be
      // rendering /login for instance
      console.log(req.data.page && req.data.page._url);
      return callback(null);
    };
  }
};
```

Apostrophe always calls `pageBeforeSend` for every module that has such a method.

As seen above, take care not to assume `req.data.page` is set, since there are a few cases where Apostrophe renders a full webpage as a response but there is no corresponding page object in Apostrophe's page tree.

#### Intercepting right after the page object is loaded

One more option: if `pageBeforeSend` is too late in the process for you, for instance because you want widget loaders to see changes you've made to `req`, use `pageServe` instead...

```
// in app.js

var apos = require('apostrophe')({
  modules: {
    // Other module configuration here, then ...
   'cool-stuff': {}
  }
});

// lib/modules/cool-stuff/index.js

module.exports = {
  construct: function(self, options) {
    self.pageServe = function(req, callback) {
      // Express request URL
      console.log(req.url);
      // URL of the best matching page available
      console.log((req.data.page || req.data.bestPage)._url);
      return callback(null);
    };
  }
};
```

Notice that I'm allowing for either `req.data.page` or `req.data.bestPage` to exist. If the URL doesn't exactly match a page, Apostrophe will set `req.data.bestPage` to the page with the longest "path prefix" matching the URL. For instance, if the URL is /foo/bar and /foo exists but /foo/bar doesn't, `req.data.bestPage` will be `/foo`. Note that this means `req.data.bestPage` will be the homepage in the worst case.

See the `apostrophe-custom-pages` module for neat things you can do with this.

Hope this is helpful!

Comment: Now that is a comprehensive answer! Thank you for providing several different ways to do this. I went with option 2 (project level). This is the 'uncookied' case. If the cookie is present, I want to automatically add the user to Apos users (aposUsersSafe collection) and then auto sign in the user to Apos. Are both of these doable? I believe the auto sign in can be done by extending passport: http://apostrophecms.org/docs/modules/apostrophe-login/index.html. Is this the right way to try to do this? Not sure about the auto add users though. Can it be done? Thanks again for the great answer!

Comment: Those are good questions too! Would you mind posting them separately here on SO so that it is easier for others to find the answers? Thanks!